# Create post button disabled in reddit

Tags: reddit

[image]

The above pic describes the current situation. I am able to write the contents of a post but I am unable to create it as the button is grayed out.

Any differentials on the reason behind this?

Comment: This could be a browser issue. Logout from your account and try to clear cache from the browser, log-in again and try.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this same issue and solved it; based on your screenshot I think my solution will be applicable to you as well:

You have to write a title to your post, then the "post" button will be enabled.  :)

Comment: LOLLLLLL! HAd the same thing; searching for over an hour. OMG! What commenting (without titles) does to our brains.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too! Wonder why they wouldn't just prompt to enter the title? Isn't that what Javascript's for? :) Weird.